# Backup app from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, backup, itunes

Im having a problem with my app when the user restore it into another iPhone, i made a fix and i need to test, so short question:

It is possible to backup an app installed from Xcode in iTunes and restore in another iPhone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research and test i can say its not possible...